# Saving an output file during merging on QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I am using QGIS for Landsat 7 data and under raster> miscellaneous > merge I am trying to save the output file, however I don't know where to save it as everything I press asks me to 'open' it rather than 'save' it.

Comment: Can you provide screen shots of what you see?

Comment: did you check "choose directory instead of files" and click on the button next to "input directory"?

Comment: I can't post a screen shot, so I'll try and explain a bit better I didn't check 'choose input directory instead of files' but I managed to get an input and output file. I then pressed layer stack but then when I pressed okay a pop up box saying 'Format driver GMT does not support creation and piecewise writing. Please select a format that does such as GF iff (the default) or HFA (Erdas Imagine). However for both files I made sure they were GF iff.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is that when you use the merge tool under `Raster> Miscellaneous > Merge` you clicked on the button beside `Input files` instead of `Output file` as you can see below:

[image]

The input files will lead you to the next option that you have to `Open` (choose) the files that you want to merge:

[image]

However when you press on the Select beside the Output file:

[image]

You will have the option to `Save` the output file:

[image]

I suspect this is what has happened to you.