# GMT instead GTiff while merging rasters: error message

Tags: qgis, raster, error, gdal-merge, gmt

My question is linked to that post ([Saving an output file during merging on QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222254/saving-an-output-file-during-merging-on-qgis/266339#266339)) as I have exactly the same issue but as the guy couldn't provide screenshots and the post is unachieved, I ask again the question:

I'm using QGIS 2.18, I try to merge two rasters (geotiff files) raster> miscellaneous >merge, while trying to merge I have an error message

Methodolgy: 
I uncheck the choose input directory instead of files. 
I select my two input files ( raster so ".tiff" files ) I define my output files ( .tiff as well ) Like showed in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJEW7kckIeg&feature=youtu.be (and the screenshot showed in the other post) but after that, in 'the summary box', the code is in "GMT" instead of "GTiff" like show in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJEW7kckIeg&feature=youtu.be (1 min30)

Picture  from the video (1 min30)

[image]

What I have

[image]

And the Error message when I click on "OK"

[image]

Even if I manually change the "GMT" to "GTiff" with the pen, it automatically comes back to the "GMT"

Could someone help me?

Comment: See https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16979 and https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17035

Comment: Indeed, it's not exactly what I expect as the answer but "issues.qgis.org/issues/16979 and issues.qgis.org/issues/17035" seems to be the solution, I didn't come across these cases when I looked on the internet for an existing topic before to asked so thanks for your help AndreJ! ;)